# Как сделать автоматическое закрытие всплывающего окна через несколько секунд?

Tags: javascript

На странице используется всплывающее окно, код которого представлен ниже. 
Как сделать автоматическое закрытие окна через 3 секунды после открытия?

**HTML:**

```
<div id="dim">
<div class="msgbox">
Контент окна
</div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

            $("#dim").css("height", $(document).height());

            $(".alert").click(function(){
                $("#dim").fadeIn();
                return false;
            });

            $(".close").click(function(){
                $("#dim").fadeOut();
                return false;
            });

        });

        $(window).bind("resize", function(){
            $("#dim").css("height", $(window).height());
        });
```

Comment: повесить timeout на 3 секунды с скрытием

Comment: Знать бы ещё, куда его повесить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    function hideAlert(){
        $("#dim").fadeOut();
        return false;
    }

    function showAlert(callback, timeout){
        $("#dim").fadeIn("fast", function(){
            if(typeof callback == "function")
                setTimeout(callback, parseInt(timeout) > 0 ? timeout : 5000); //По умолчанию скрываем через 5 сек.
        });
        return false;
    }

    $(".alert").click(function(){
        showAlert(hideAlert, 3000); //Закроет окно через 3 сек. после завершения анимации fadeIn
    });

    $(".close").click(function(){
        hideAlert();
    });
```

Comment: Что-то здесь слишком много кода. Куда его в моём коде вставить нужно, скажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Заменить им ваши $(".alert").click... и $(".close").click...

Answer (score 1):

```
setTimeout(function() {$(".имя класса формы или блока").fadeOut()}, 3000)
```

Comment: А куда нужно вставить этот код?

Comment: @Виктор Павлов, до остального вашего кода добавьте http://jsfiddle.net/bVAa9/

Comment: Почему-то ничего не работает.

Comment: @Виктор Павлов, выложите на http://jsfiddle.net весь ваш код

Comment: Как туда выложить? Не получается.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DFWyk/ выложил. Но проблема в том, что при первом нажатии скрывается блок (как мне показалось, слишком быстро), при втором открытии он уже не скрывается.